# Solr Search Across Multiple Cores not working quering on specific field

Tags: solr

I have two Solr cores. 
Core0 and core1

Both cores are having same schema and configuration.
after indexing both cores data is retried from both cores individually

This url is working

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?shards=localhost:8983/solr/core0,localhost:8983/solr/core1&q=iPo*
```

but when i searched on a specific field than it is not working

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?shards=localhost:8983/solr/core0,localhost:8983/solr/core1&q=mnemonic_value:"United"
```

Why distributed search is not working when i search on a particular field?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following for your field `mnemonic_value`:

- That it is defined with the property `indexed=true` in your schema.xml file in both cores.
- Examine the `type` that you have defined for this field. If it is not text type fields, you may need to experiment with your query terms to get a matching result or change it to one of the text types defined in your schema.xml.